# npm is failing to compile – uikit3

Tags: npm, frameworks, getuikit

I've just started using UIKit3 (getuitkit.com) and I keep getting this error when npm run watch is running – I also can't use npm run compile either. Any ideas?
This is the error I get with watch...

```
[compile-less] /Users/Michael/Sites/uikit-3/build/icons.js:10
glob(custom, (err, folders) =>
                            ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
[compile-less] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

And this for compile...

```
/Users/Michael/Sites/uikit-3/build/icons.js:10
glob(custom, (err, folders) =>
                            ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "icons"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! uikit@3.0.0-beta.18 icons: `node build/icons`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the uikit@3.0.0-beta.18 icons script 'node build/icons'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the uikit package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build/icons
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls uikit
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Michael/Sites/uikit-3/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "compile-less"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! uikit@3.0.0-beta.18 compile-less: `npm run icons && node build/less`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the uikit@3.0.0-beta.18 compile-less script 'npm run icons && node build/less'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the uikit package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run icons && node build/less
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls uikit
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Michael/Sites/uikit-3/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "compile"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! uikit@3.0.0-beta.18 compile: `npm run compile-less && npm run compile-js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the uikit@3.0.0-beta.18 compile script 'npm run compile-less && npm run compile-js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the uikit package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run compile-less && npm run compile-js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls uikit
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Michael/Sites/uikit-3/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running node v0.12.0. UIkit's build tools require a minimum version of 4.4+. Please update to a current Node version. https://nodejs.org/en/